# one to many (or one) cascade create view

Tags: grails, one-to-many, scaffolding, one-to-one, create-view

I have two domains:

```
class A {
 String name
 B b
}

class B {
 String code
}
```

I use the default scaffolding. When I go to the A list view I cannot create an A instace because I miss a B instance; here the gsp

```
<g:if test="${B?.list()}">
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <g:link class="create" action="create" controller="b">
        <g:message code="default.new.label" args="['b']" />
    </g:link>
</g:else>
```

If i click on the create B link I'm able to create a B instance but I lose the "connection" to the A object I'm creating.
There is a good way to support the user in this scenario?
An idea could be open the create B link in a modal box, could be?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the ID of the A to params:

```
<g:link class="create" action="create" controller="b" params="[ 'a.id': aInstance.id ]">
```

The key just adapt to the relation attribute in the domain class B.

Comment: I found a work around: A create link hidden and create B showed (with warning) if no B instances present.
Using Tom solution I must have an a.id but I'm creating and A instance and it isn't persisted yet; is it right?

Comment: From your description I have understood, that the instance of A already exists (list of A). If the instance does not exists yet, than is my solution not usable. I you need to create both domains, you can use Commands objects and special action, which uses the data from the Command object and creates both A and B instances.